# Get position of GameObject from script in it or in other GameObject

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

In Unity AR Fundation
In a project, once you have selected a point on the screen, I generate a plane and create objects on it. Once the plan is created, how do I get its position from another script so that I can generate the items there?
Or how can I get his position on a script in the plan?

Comment: If it is on the same object: `transform.position` ... From another object `theOtherGameObject.transform.position` .. ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in order to get a position from an object, you need a reference to it. You can acquire it in several ways.

Here are some options:

1. Using [`FindObjectOfType`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.FindObjectOfType.html) (assuming your plane has some kind of a unique script attached or it's assigned on a variable that is attached to that script you're looking for)
2. Using [`GameObject.Find`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html) which will look for for an object that matches a specific name
3. Using a [`static`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/static) field which can be accessed from anywhere (upon creating your plane, you'll have to assign it to a static field)

When it comes to accessing the position of a `GameObject` you can do that in the following way:

```
yourGameObject.transform.position
```