# How do I find the location of an object through code

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to attach the camera to a character's xPos without grouping the camera to the player

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get position of GameObject from script in it or in other GameObject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66944374/get-position-of-gameobject-from-script-in-it-or-in-other-gameobject)

Answer (score 0):

The thing to be careful about is whether you mean you want the camera to be linked to the character's *local* x-position or if you want the camera to be linked to the character's *world* x-position. The two will vary based on the transforms of the character's parent GameObjects.

You can either tag the character and find it by doing a lookup in `Start()` or you can make the character reference a `public GameObject targetCharacter` in your camera script and set the reference manually in the editor.

Once you determine how you're going to do it:

```
public class CameraLocator : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject targetCharacter;
void Start()
{
    if(targetCharacter == null)
    { 
        targetCharacter = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("YourCharacterTag");
        if(targetCharacter == null)
        {
            Debug.LogError("targetCharacter is not set and could not be found!");
        }
    }
}
void Update()
{
    if(targetCharacter != null)
    {
        var camPosition = this.gameObject.transform.position;
        var targetPosition = targetCharacter.transform.position;
        camPosition.x = targetPosition.x;
        this.gameObject.transform.position = camPosition;
    }
}
```